# How to use if statement in php?

Tags: php

I have a problem with php if statement. I want to display propere status user. If user is friend, it should display friend. If user is wainting, should display wainting. And if user not friend and wainting, should display add. This code below, display always only Friend. I don't know why. If someone help me I will gratefull.

```js
 <input type="submit" name="addFriend" id="button_color" value="<?php if ($this->status == 'Friend'): ?> Friend <?php elseif ($this->status == 'Wainting'): ?> Wainting <?php else: ?> Add <?php endif; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<input type="submit" name="addFriend" id="button_color" value="<?php if ($this->status == 'Friend'){ echo 'Friend'; } elseif ($this->status == 'Wainting'){ echo 'Wainting';} else{echo 'Add'; ?>">
```